# what exactly the undo information lives in oracle?

Tags: oracle, rdbms

some docs says, there are "undo tablespaces" implies that we should create a tablespace for undo imformation.

some docs says, there are just "undo segment" implies that the undo information lives in normal tablespaces and just use some of it's segment.

so, what exactly the undo information lives and organized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier releases of Oracle Database used rollback segments to store undo. Oracle9i introduced automatic undo management, which simplifies undo space management by eliminating the complexities associated with rollback segment management. Oracle strongly recommends (Oracle 9i and on words) to use undo tablespace (automatic undo management) to manage undo rather than rollback segments.

When creating an UNDO tablespace, these are automatically created:

> n undo segments (based on SESSIONS parameter value) named as _SYSSMUn$
>   owned by PUBLIC (usable for OPS configuration) not manually manageable